# disable launch image from the app

Tags: ios, xcode

i want to disable launch image from my app. I am already having a splash screen so on the app launch its showing launch image first and then the splash screen. i want to disable the launch image and just show splash screen on app launch.please help. thanks in advance

Comment: remove the Default.png & Default@2x.png from your project. Now, launch images will not be shown and you may display your splash screen.

Comment: If you remove the launch image you will just get a black screen. The best thing to do is to create a launch image that looks the same as your splash screen initial state.

Answer (score 2):

you can't as — it stays up until your program has been loaded and returned from `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`:
As Launch Image is displayed when the app loads.and the splash means you want to show some etc information. And Apple recommends using a screenshot of your app main window, so it appears that your app launch faster

Answer (score 2):

As you can't disable the splash, the usual hack is to make it look just like your own splash screen. It'll transition nicely from one to the other

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1**:
Check your `Default.png` and `Default@2x.png` and `Default-568h@2x.png` 
If that is not your file then remove from project..

**Solution 2**:
Add your splashscreen Image in three types and remname as `Default.png` and `Default@2x.png` and `Default-568h@2x.png`