# How to disable the splash screen on iOS?

Tags: ios, delphi, firemonkey

How to disable the splash screen on iOS using XE7?
I could not find an option to disable it from the project options as it exists with Android.

Comment: If the option is there for Android but not for iOS, I would automatically assume that iOS enforces a splash screen (which it does).Apple is very picky. You might get away with just a black image, but then again your app might be rejected from the app store.

Comment: Jerry, I don't think that it's an Apple requirement but rather a Delphi issue, 99% of the app installed on iOS devices don't have a splash screen.

Comment: possible duplicate of [disable launch image from the app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16733920/disable-launch-image-from-the-app) (And this is not related to Delphi). Where did you get this 99% figure?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

iOS strictly enforces some sort of image for a startup screen - [even if it's just a black image or a snapshot of your main screen.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16733920/disable-launch-image-from-the-app) The Android and iOS platforms are very different, and this is one of their big differences.

When you launch your app, whether you notice it or not, there is always a delay while loading your app. The same applies for any platform. Apple took advantage of this delay and decided to enforce the presence of a startup screen (or splash screen). If you do not wish to show any image here, your choices are:

- Exclude any image to just show empty black space
- Use a snapshot of the initial state of the main screen

Comment: Thanks for your reply Jerry. I'll follow your advice.